# Is there a supplementary repository for CentOS?

Tags: centos, rhel, repository

I saw `rhel-7-server-supplementary-rpms` repository needed in a solution. It seems that it refers to `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Server - Supplementary (RPMs)` repository.

Is there a supplementary repository for CentOS or is this RHEL exclusive repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories there isn't a "Supplemental" repo, per se, but I would guess that the packages you're looking for would be available somewhere in the repos on that page.